# F#: Why do I have to explicitly specify 'unit' for functions taking no arguments?

Tags: syntax, f#, function

So I've just about finished my first F# program, with my only functional background being *a little bit* of knowledge of Haskell (read: Haven't really produced any programs in it).

After experiencing some boggling behavior, I came to realize that F# makes a differentiation between:

```
prepareDeck = allSuits |> List.collect generateCards |> shuffle
```

and

```
prepareDeck() = allSuits |> List.collect generateCards |> shuffle
```

I noticed that it "caches" the former, never recalculating it if it's called again, whereas it treats the latter like a normal function. You can't tell the difference if the function in question doesn't have side effects, obviously, but my `shuffle` did!

Was this supposed to be common knowledge? I haven't seen it mentioned on any tutorial materials yet. Is the reason just a weakness in the parser, kinda like how you **have** to declare a function before you use it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most F# material *does* explain that all top-level statements in a module are executed from top-down on declaration. In other words, what you've declared isn't a function, but a value which is bound once when the program runs.

It really helps to see the reflected code. I have a simple file:

```
let juliet = "awesome"
let juliet2() = "awesome"
```

The compiled code looks something like this:

```
public static string juliet
{
    [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
    get
    {
        return "awesome";
    }
}

//...

public static string juliet2()
{
    return "awesome";
}
```

So one is a static property, the other is a function. This is a desirable property, because imagine if we had something like this:

```
let x = someLongRunningDatabaseCall()
```

We only want `x` to be bound once, we don't want it to invoke database function everytime we access `x`.

Additionally, we can write interesting code like this:

```
> let isInNebraska =
    printfn "Creating cities set"
    let cities = set ["Omaha"; "Bellevue"; "Lincoln"; "Papillion"; "La Vista"; "Ralston"]
    fun n -> cities.Contains(n);;
Creating cities set

val isInNebraska : (string -> bool)

> isInNebraska "Omaha";;
val it : bool = true

> isInNebraska "Okaloosa";;
val it : bool = false
```

Since `isInNebraska` is a value, its evaluated immediately. It just so happens that its datatype is `(string -> bool)`, so it *looks* like a function. As a result, we only fill our `cities` set once even if we invoke the function 1000 times.

Let's compare that code to this:

```
> let isInNebraska2 n =
    printfn "Creating cities set"
    let cities = set ["Omaha"; "Bellevue"; "Lincoln"; "Papillion"; "La Vista"; "Ralston"]
    cities.Contains(n);;

val isInNebraska2 : string -> bool

> isInNebraska2 "Omaha";;
Creating cities set
val it : bool = true

> isInNebraska2 "Okaloosa";;
Creating cities set
val it : bool = false
```

Oops, we're creating a new cities set everytime we invoke the function.

So there is definitely a legitimate and real distinction between values and functions.

Comment: Nice example.  For anyone who's interested, the "Expert F#" book (chapter 8) develops this discussion a bit further in the context of designing functions for efficient partial application.

Comment: I think there's a flaw here: there's not much difference between a static property and a static method in that **both are methods** behind the scenes, and an access to a property is actually a method call (that's why you can mark a property as *virtual*). I can't see your "desirable property".

Comment: I believe that the difference is that when you have `let julietNoFunction = ...` the static property will simply return a value stored on a static field, and this value is calculated only once at the static constructor of the generated type for the module. I think I've seen this in Reflector, but I'm not sure anymore. Anyways, the way you present it does not show any advantages at all on using `let juliet = ...` over `let juliet() = ...`.

Answer (score 6):

This is how things work in practically every language with side effects.

```
let name = expr
```

runs the code 'now', and may cause side-effects if `expr` has effects.  Subsequent references to `name` have no effects.  Whereas

```
let name() = expr
```

defines a function, has no effects now, and will evaluate (and have effects) every time `name()` is invoked.

Comment: Gotcha. Guess I was confused because F# is the first language I've used that is functional but side-effecty.